# Multiple Arrays in TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

I have a simple TableView app that has 2 static cells labeled Make and Model. Once you click 'make', a segue takes you to all the car makes, once you select it, it disappears and the value is stored on the detailLabelText on the Make cell. My question is, is it possible to store multiple arrays in one tableViewController for the Model tableView controller based on what Make you have chosen it will populate with the correct array? Instead of having 25 different TableViewControllers that you need to hook up segues too.

I don't have the code, since I don't know where start on this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes. In your tableview controller, you could use the indexPath.row integer returned from didSelectRowAtIndexPath. This could then be passed across to your destination view controller in your segue, which could then use this value to choose the appropriate array of models to populate the next tableview.

For example, in your main view controller (i.e. wherever they are choosing the make of car)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    modelView *myView = [segue destinationViewController];
    myView.carMakeSelected = self.carMakeSelected;  // you could populate this from your didSelectRowAtIndex...
}
```

Then, in your destination view controller, declare a property called carMakeSelected, then have some conditional code in your ViewDidLoad to choose the appropriate list of models. For example, something like;

```
if (self.carMakeSelected ==1)
{
modelsOfCar = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mercedesCars];
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: how would I go about selecting the arrays in the destination controller? @Gismay